# How to select just rows that contains integers and decimals in sql oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to select just integers and decimal ones from my procedure. In this case 192 and 193.0. What I have tried is regexp_like(columnName, '^[[:digit:]]*$') but it just appears 192 (integer ones). 
Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: what version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
regexp_like(columnName, '^[[:digit:]]*(\.[[:digit:]]+)?$')
```

That allows an optional point followed by at least one digit to follow the first sequence of digits.

Answer (score 0):

How about `TRANSLATE`?

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Negativo' from dual union all
  3     select '192'      from dual union all
  4     select '193.3'    from dual union all
  5     select '20.a4'    from dual
  6    )
  7  select col
  8  from test
  9  where translate(col, '0123456789.', 'a') is null;

COL
--------
192
193.3

SQL>
```

Comment: You seem to be translating '0' to 'a', guess that is a typo.

Comment: @Padders, in this case it is OK as I'm looking for numerics only. However, yes - if sample data contained zero as the first character, then it should be modified to e.g. `translate(col, 'a0123456789.', 'a')`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IsNumeric(Expression IN VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER IS
   val NUMBER;
BEGIN
    val := TO_NUMBER(Expression);
    RETURN 1; 
EXCEPTION
    WHEN VALUE_ERROR OR INVALID_NUMBER THEN
        RETURN 0; 
END IsNumeric;
```

Comment: Watch out for this with higher plsql_optimize_level, the assignment to val may get optimized away.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 12.2 or above, you can use the [`default <value> on conversion error` clause](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html#GUID-D4807212-AFD7-48A7-9AED-BEC3E8809866) to return a default value when the str can't be converted to a number.

e.g.:

```
select 'abc' str, to_number('abc' default null on conversion error) str_num
from   dual;

str str_num
--- -------
abc
```

See [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c9370446d1bbf9f1902ea4cfd7465c17) for a demo.